# Calling parseInt with a string which represents a value larger than Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

Tags: javascript, integer

I would like to ask about the behavior of `parseInt` when called with a string which represents an integer value larger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`.

Technically, I assume I should be expecting the same outcome which I would get by using that value directly (i.e., as a number rather than as a string).

For example, the following two will yield the same value (whether its accurate or not):

- `const x = parseInt("0x100000000000000000000000000000000");`
- `const x = 0x100000000000000000000000000000000;`

I do understand, however, that perhaps JS doesn't guarantee this.

So what I would really like to know is whether I can at least count on `parseInt` to return a value different than 0, when called with a string which represents an integer value larger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`.

Comment: It would have the exact same problems as any other number over MAX_SAFE_INTEGER, so it might work or not.

Comment: @VLAZ: Thank you. So there is possibly a very big integer out there, which when used (either as a native `Number`, or as a string passed to `parseInt`), will "wrap around" to zero?

Comment: It won't wrap around but it will be *imprecise*. With large numbers you can get `2 + 2 = 5` or other weird behaviour. Ultimately, it's the underlying binary digits that are not enough to represent the numbers.

Comment: @VLAZ: Yes, but aren't we guaranteed that at least one of those binary digits will be different than 0 (with regards to my bottom-line question)? Also, please note that I wasn't asking about imprecision. That issue I am already aware of (I thought it was clear from the fact that I've explicitly mentioned `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` in my question).

Comment: You can think of floating point representation as scientific notation, e.g., `1.2e24` - you keep the front and last digits (significant and exponent) and going *too high* devotes more digits to the exponent `1.2e48` will be a higher number but you still express it with the same number of digits. So if you go "too high" you're still going to get a number that is *close* but you won't be able to work out what the actual one is - `1.001e3` would be transformed into `1001` but if you truncate to, say, one decimal `1.0e3` would be understood as 1000 and you loose that last digit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is fundamental with number representations - *any* numeric that is over `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` is not safe for use any more. Basic example:

```js
const max = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
const maxPlus1 = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 1;
const maxPlus2 = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 2;

console.log("max:", max); //9007199254740991
console.log("max + 1:", maxPlus1); //9007199254740992
console.log("max + 2:", maxPlus2); //9007199254740992

console.log("max + 1 = max + 2:", maxPlus1 === maxPlus2); //true
```

As you can see, almost immediately after you breach the `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` barrier, you run into problems with precision. JavaScript uses the [IEEE 754  standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) to represents numbers and while it can show numbers than its highest (as opposed to, say an `int` field in another language which will overflow to zero or maximum negative), such representations are *imprecise*. Some big numbers cannot be represented like  `9007199254740993` (which is `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 2`) and you get a different number instead.

The exact same thing applies to `parseInt`, since it will convert the string into a JavaScript numeric, there might not be a precise representation for it:

```js
const maxPlus1String = "9007199254740992";
const maxPlus2String = "9007199254740993";

const maxPlus1 = parseInt(maxPlus1String);
const maxPlus2 = parseInt(maxPlus2String);

console.log("max + 1:", maxPlus1); //9007199254740992
console.log("max + 2:", maxPlus2); //9007199254740992

console.log("(string) max + 1 = max + 2:", maxPlus1String === maxPlus2String); //false
console.log("max + 1 = max + 2:", maxPlus1 === maxPlus2); //true
```

Ultimately, it's a question of how floating point numbers are represented. [Wikipedia has a good article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) but I'll simplify it to the most important parts:

With floating point representation, you keep a *mantissa* (also called *significand* with **d** at the end) and *exponent* for each number. This works like scientific notation, so I'll use that for easier referencing:

> 1.23e5 = 1.23 * 10<sup>5</sup> = 123 000

- `1.23` is the **mantissa** of the number.
- `5` is the **exponent**.

With both of these, you can represent numbers arbitrarily high in very short form. However, with floating point representation, you are limited to how many bits of each you can keep. This comes at the cost of sacrificing accuracy once you run out of numbers for the mantissa, you lose precision. So, if we decide to only allow one decimal place in our scientific notation, we get the number `1.2e5` which *could* be 123 000 but it might also be 120 000 or 125 000 or 128 215 - we cannot recreate it from the shortened form. Similar thing happens with floating point numbers - once you don't have enough digits for the mantissa, the rest are discarded, so you don't get the exact number back.

When the exponent runs out of digits you reach the highest number representable.

In JavaScript, the maximum number possible can be seen in `Number.MAX_VALUE`:

```js
console.log(Number.MAX_VALUE)
```

`1.7976931348623157e+308` is *pretty large*, with an exponent of `308`. So you can represent a lot of numbers with this and if you use `parseInt` anything under this value, you will get *some* number that is in the region of what you parsed.

However, what happens if you go *over*? Well, you'll reach a value within the number range that is representable in JavaScript which is reserved for a special reason. This is the *absolute* top most number - a floating point representation for the largest number possible to be represented. That value is `Infinity`. If you happen to parse something that is larger than `Number.MAX_VALUE`, you'll get `Infinity` instead:

```js
const largeNum = "17" + "0".repeat(307); //1.7e308
const tooLargeNum = "18" + "0".repeat(307); //1.8e308

console.log("large number string:", largeNum);
console.log("large number parsed:", parseInt(largeNum));


console.log("too large number string:", tooLargeNum);
console.log("too large number parsed:", parseInt(tooLargeNum));
```

So, even if you have astronomically large numbers, you are *guaranteed* to have a number more than zero, since `Infinity > 0`

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is good, but like I said, my question is not about imprecision, as I am pretty aware of this issue. I wanted to know: 1. Whether I can count on `praseInt(str)` to return the exact same value that I would get by using `str` directly as an native number. 2. Whether I can at least count on it to return a value different than 0.

Comment: So can you guarantee that for every string which represents an integer between 2^53 and (roughly) 10^309, `praseInt` will return a non-zero value?

Comment: @goodvibration yes, I can. There is no "wrap around" like an `int` field in, say, C++ or Java - those are bounded integers. I've explained (briefly) how floating point works - if you represent a number higher than what precision allows you *lose precision*, you don't get completely different numbers. The precision loss means you get a number which has a *similar* value, so you won't get orders of magnitude different.